# NUCLEO-F207ZG / STM32F207ZG supply voltage

Tags: stm32, nucleo

I need to change the wait states via the Flash access control register for an STM32F207ZG on a NUCLEO-F207ZG board.

The reference manual gives a table that tells you  how many wait states you need based on the clock frequency of the cortex M3 in MHz and the 'supply voltage of the device'. But how do I determine the correct voltage range?? The voltage ranges given are "2.7 to 3.6", "2.4 to 2.7", "2.1 to 2.4" and "1.8 to 2.1 V. The supply voltage to the board is 5V over Usb but that is not mentioned in the table. I assume the board drops some voltage to step it down to what the stm32 chip requires. However I can't find any mention of what that voltage is and so I'm at a complete loss as to which voltage range I need to select.

Comment: Nucleo-144 seems to be a term used for a family of 25 variants.  Can you specify the exact part?

Comment: Pages 23-24 of this datasheet https://www.digikey.ch/htmldatasheets/production/2264408/0/0/1/stm32-nucleo-144-user-manual.html suggest that the core voltage can be varied.

Comment: Hi @Frog -- edited to include the part number. It's essentially just nucleo-144 + the stm32 model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [schematics](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f207zg.html#cad-resources) for this board show that the `VDD` net is connected to `+3V3` via JP5, so unless you've removed that link to provide another supply, we can assume that `VDD=+3.3v`.

As you mention, the number of wait states depends on the core frequency, and voltage at VDD.

The [datasheet](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f207zg.html#) for the part states that for "*VDD=2.7 to 3.6V*", you can access the flash at up to 30 MHz with 0 wait states, increasing to 3 wait states at ~90MHz or above.

I've included Figure 21 from the datasheet below, but Table 15 is also relevant.

[image: a graph showing the number of wait states vs the core frequency and voltage at VDD]